# LaTex error: missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: errors

I am one week into writing my thesis. We have a Latex template at our university. My latex was working fine and suddenly I got this error `missing \endcsname inserted`. I have even tried to disable the chapter I was working on while this error happened, but that didn't solve the problem. The error starts from the `\begin{document}` part. What should I do?

```
%\documentclass[croppedpdf,pagebackref,showinstructions]{adsphd}
%\documentclass[pagebackref,showinstructions,showlabels,biblatex,biber,biblatexstyle=authoryear]{adsphd}
%\documentclass[online]{adsphd}
\documentclass[print]{adsphd}
%\documentclass[pagebackref,showinstructions,showlabels,coverfontpercent=100]{adsphd}

% To use biblatex:
%\documentclass[biblatex,biblatexstyle=authoryear,showinstructions,showlabels]{adsphd}

% Preamble {{{}{

\usepackage[english,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{nomencl}   % For nomenclature
\usepackage[style=long,number=none]{glossary} % For list of abbreviations
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

% !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
% !!                                                               !!
% !!  WARNING: do not remove the following lines between           !!
% !!  "%%% COVER: Settings %%%" and "%%% COVER: End settings %%%"  !!
% !!                                                               !!
% !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

%%% COVER: Settings %%%
\title{Sustainable materialisation of residues from thermal processes into construction materials}
%\subtitle{Construction materials from stainless steel slags}

\author{Muhammad}{Salman}

\supervisor{Prof.~dr.~ir.~Koen~van Balen}{}
%\cosupervisor{Prof.~dr.~ir.~R.Cools}{}
%\president{Prof.~dr.~ir.~De~Voorzitter}
\jury{Prof.~xxxxx\\
      Prof.~xxxxx
}
\externaljurymember{Prof.~xxxxx~jurylid}{xxx}

\phddegree{Engineering} % "Doctor of ..."
\faculty{Faculty of Engineering}
\department{Department of Civil Engineering}
%\researchgroup{Scientific Computing Group}
\address{Kasteelpark Arenberg 40 box 2448}
% \addresscity{B-3001 Heverlee} % This is the default value. Note
                                % that 'B-3001 Leuven' is _incorrect_!!
                                % [http://www.kuleuven.be/communicatie/schrijven/taalgebruik.html]
\email{muhammad.salman@bwk.kuleuven.be} % Leave empty to hide
\website{http://www.bwk.kuleuven.be} % Leave empty to hide

\date{XXXX 2014}
%\udc{XXX.XX}            % UDC is no longer necessary.
\depot{XXXX/XXXX/XX}     % Leave out the initial D/ (it is added
                         % automatically)
\isbn{XXX-XX-XXXX-XXX-X}


% Set spine width:
\setlength{\adsphdspinewidth}{9mm}

%% Set bleeds
%\setlength{\defaultlbleed}{7mm}
%\setlength{\defaultrbleed}{7mm}

% Set custom cover page
% \setcustomcoverpage{mycoverpage.tex} % mycoverpage.tex is the default

%%% COVER: End settings %%%

% for the nomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\makeatletter
\let\@printnomenclatureorig\@printnomenclature
\def\@printnomenclature[#1]{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \chaptermark{\nomname}
  \@printnomenclatureorig[#1]
}
\makeatother
\makenomenclature

% for the list of abbreviations. 
\newcommand{\glossname}{Abbreviations}
\makeglossary

% To avoid problems, do NOT change the layout of the following two
% commands
\let\printglossaryorig\printglossary
\renewcommand{\printglossary}{%
  \renewcommand{\glossaryname}{\glossname}
  \cleardoublepage%
  \printglossaryorig\chaptermark{\glossname}}

% Specify the .bib file
\bibliography{allpapers}
%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
% Bibtex style
%\bibstyle{abbrv}
%\bibstyle{plain}
%\bibstyle{acm}
\bibstyle{ieeetr}

% Own commands
\InputIfFileExists{defs} % defs.tex, contains own preamble settings

% }{}}}  <-- Preamble

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\makefrontcover
\makefrontcoverXII

\maketitle

\frontmatter % to get \pagenumbering{roman}

\includepreface{acknowledgment}
\includeabstract{abstract}
\includeabstractnl{abstractnl}

% To create a list of abbreviations, there are 2 options
% 1. manual creation and inclusion of this file
%    \includeabbreviations{abbreviations}
% 2. automatic generation via the glossary package
%    \usepackage{glossary}
%    \makeglossary
%    \glossary{name=MD,description=molecular dynamics}
%    \printglossary
\printglossary

% To create a list of symbols, there are 2 options
% 1. include a manually created nomenclature as a chapter
%    \includenomenclature{nomenclaturechapter}
% 2. automatic generation via the nomencl package
%    \usepackage{nomencl}
%    \makenomenclature
%    \nomenclature[cB]{$c_B(\vec{x})$}{Characteristic function of $B$}
%    \printnomenclature[3cm]
\printnomenclature[1.5cm]

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

% Show an overview of todos with page numbers...
%\listoftodos


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\mainmatter % to get \pagenumbering{arabic}

% Show instructions on a separate page
\instructionschapters\cleardoublepage

\includechapter{chapter1}
\includechapter{chapter2}
\includechapter{chapter3}
\includechapter{chapter4}
\includechapter{chapter5}
\includechapter{chapter6}
\includechapter{chapter7}
\includechapter{chapter8}
% Insert here your own chapters
% Chapters are expected to be in a tex-file with the given name dot
% tex and in a directory with the given name in the chapters
% directory.

%\includechapter{conclusion}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\appendix

%\includeappendix{myappendix}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\backmatter

\includebibliography
\instructionsbibliography

\includecv{curriculum}

\includepublications{publications}

%\makebackcover
\makebackcoverXII

\end{document}

% vim: tw=70 nocindent expandtab foldmethod=marker foldmarker={{{}{,}{}}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). You should edit your question to add a link to the `adsphd.cls` file; otherwise, people here won't be able to compile your code.

Comment: Try deleting the `.aux` file. Failing that, edit your question so that it includes a complete example which reproduces the problem. Without this it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: ok. so, the codes i have put is from the main file, my chapters (currently 8) are on a separate file. Everything was fine till i entered a table in Ch. 8. and i started getting the following error

Comment: ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.114 \begin{document}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.114 \begin{document}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
! Extra \endcsname.
\check@bm@number ...0\else \csname B_#1\endcsname
\fi
l.114 \begin{document}
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\relax

Comment: following this, i tried again by removing the table and also disabling the chapter itself, but the same error remains...

Comment: @user48392 You're not helping people wanting to help you. The error apparently happens during the reading of the `.aux` file which has become corrupt for some reason; try removing it before compiling again. I suspect you have something dangerous in some sectional title, but the clues you're providing are not conclusive.

Comment: i did delete the .aux file and compiled, got the same error. quite novice here, could you pls help me with something specific that i should add....

Comment: @egreg just to add, i deleted the .aux file from the main folder and also from the chapter i was working on at that time, and i am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Delete every automatically generated file (`.aux`, `.toc`, etc.) and try again.

Comment: @IanThompson I deleted all of them, but i am still getting the same error as mentioned above. What more I find now is that not only my project but no or Latex project is compiling on my computer any more :(, for example, even when i am running the templet of my thesis in a separate folder is not making any changes to the pdf file.

Comment: It is solved now. actually the problem was with Miktex. i had to reinstall it and then manually create the memory dump file "pdflatex", and it started working. thanks for the help....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a highly localised problem with the OP's TeX installation.